# Grafana Odata Plugin

Tags: grafana

I use the Odata-Plugin on Grafana and want to create a timeline on the x-axis. If there somebody who has an idear how can i do this? (Grafana-enterprise)

2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
7500
1500
6000
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
0
0
0
2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
7192
0
719
this is showing at the table view, but actually the specified time period goes from Janaur 2022 until now

i allready tried all panel options, but nothink works. If i use the time series, everythink is fine.